# Is there a speed problem when using pragma pack?

Tags: c++

```
struct window_data
{
    window_props win_props;
    bool VSync;

    Window::event_callback_fn EventCallback;
};
```

I have this struct in my program.
sizeof(window_data) equals 120.

```
#pragma pack(push, 2)
struct window_data
{
    window_props win_props;
    bool VSync;

    Window::event_callback_fn EventCallback;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

If i use #pragma pack(push, 2), sizeof(window_data) equals 114.

```
#pragma pack(push, 1)
struct window_data
{
    window_props win_props;
    bool VSync;

    Window::event_callback_fn EventCallback;
};
#pragma pack(pop)
```

And in this case, sizeof(window_data) equals 113.

So, is there a problem with using the latest case?

Comment: Have you measured on your target platform?

Comment: Yes. There is since fields are not aligned. Data are aligned to optimize speed of accessing memory. On hardware level memory is access by whole words (of size depending on platform). Also on some platforms accessing not aligned data will lead to a crash (for example for floats on ARM).

Comment: Using packed data structures will usually result in a slight decrease in speed. CPUs are designed to work on words of memory (~8 bytes on x64 systems). If a value is not aligned to a word of memory, the CPU needs to spend a little extra time shifting the value in the registers before it can do work on the value. It may also need to perform more memory lookups as some unaligned values may be spread across the boundary of a word of memory.

Comment: The member variables are suggested to be places in the descend order of their sizes, a compiler will use less paddings.

Comment: I think that by default packs are aligned on 8 bytes, which quite standard. From that to performance, well, you could put metrics and use _godbolt.org_ to watch the effects on the assembler.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200103-00/?p=103290

Comment: @HansPassant The article you linked is really self explanatory, thank you

Comment: @CihanBilgihan That link was only a small taste. Flip through Raymond Chen's blog when you have time. You'll learn a lot of stuff you might not need to know now, but can change the way you program for the better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the normal case, without the pragma, the compiler is going to lay out the structure with padding so that the fields are correctly aligned.   For example EventCallback is presumably a 64 bit pointer, so its address should be lined up on a 8-byte boundary.

When you use the pragma, fields may wind up not being aligned.   Depending on the CPU, this may mean using different load/store instructions to access the field, or using the normal instructions and getting degraded performance on them.

In exchange for this degraded CPU performance accessing the structure, there are a few benefits.   Packed structures have a more predictable layout and are sometimes used directly for serializing data, or accessing hardware using memory mapped IO.  They also take up less space, which may help your program fit into ram, or help your working set fit into cache.   In some cases this tradeoff is worth the CPU penalty.

You should not pack unless you have a specific reason to do so.   If you are doing it to achieve a performance benefit, then measure to confirm it's actually better.